# Creating a linked list object using js

Tags: javascript

I want to make a linked list using `custom Object` that pushes a value, pop a value, display all its content, remove an item from a specific place, and insert at a specific place as long as the value is missing from the sequence otherwise through an exception.
All of the properties should be defined using data
descriptor, prevent them from being deleted, iterated, or being modified.

I can do no more than this ... I'm new to js.

```js
        var linkedList = {};

       /* linkedList.name = 'Ahmed';
        [].push.call(linkedList, 'sad', "sd");
*/
        Object.defineProperty(linkedList, "name", {
            value: "mohamed",
            writable: false,
            configurable: false,
            enumerable: false
        })
        linkedList.next = {'sd':'as'};
```

Any help? thanks in advance

Comment: [This](https://codeburst.io/linked-lists-in-javascript-es6-code-part-1-6dd349c3dcc3) maybe? Or [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implementation-linkedlist-javascript/)?

Comment: What kind of help are you looking for? I'm sure your instructional material outlined the general process, so it seems like you're asking for someone to write the code for you.

Comment: @ Barmar 
I said that I'm new to js. If you can help do something; if you can not just scroll down to the next one! it is very easy man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a linked list it's only really important to know where the head & the tail are.
So I'd suggest something like this:

```js
function createLinkedList(firstvalue) {
  const link = {
    value: firstvalue
    next: null
  };
  return {
    head: link,
    tail: link
  }
}

function addToLinkedList(linkedList, value) {
  const link = {
    value,
    next: null
  }
  linkedList.tail.next = link;
  linkedList.tail = link;
}

let linkedList = createLinkedList("mohamed");
linkedList = addToLinkedList(linkedList, "anotherName");
```

This is just a concept, you'll have to apply it to your code obviously.

Answer (score 0):

```
class LinkedList{
  constructor(value){
   this.head = {
     value: value,
     next: null
   }
   this.length = 1;
   this.tail = this.head;
  }

  prepend(value){
   let newNode = {
     value: value,
     next: null
   }
   newNode.next = this.head;
   this.head = newNode;
   this.length++;
   return this;
  }

  append(value){
    let newNode = {
     value: value,
     next: null
   }
   this.tail.next = newNode;
   this.tail = newNode;
   this.length++;
   return this;
   }
  }
```

And then you could instantiate a new linked list and use methods as needed. I'd recommend sticking with adding end or beginning (append or prepend) values to maintain good performance.

```
 const myLinkedList = new LinkedList("mohamed")
 myLinkedList.append("anotherName")
 myLinkedList.prepend("yetAnotherNameButAsTheFirstValue")
```

This should help maintain true linked list structure where the tail will always end up with the value null.

**Prepend Steps:**

1. A newNode object is created. This is the node you will be adding to the beginning.
2. newNode.next = this.head. This way we can store the previous head in the 'next' portion of the node we are to add at the beginning.
3. newNode = this.head. newNode takes the place of this.head. All is well in the world.
4. this.length++. We increase the length of the linked list.

**Append steps:**

1. A newNode object is created. This is the node you will be adding to the end. Next is null unless you decide to append again.
2. The this.tail places the newNode in its 'next'. (this.tail.next)
3. What we call 'tail' moves to the newNode we placed in this.tail.next
4. We increase the length of the linked list.

}